# CloudFlare Not Sending If-Modified-Since Headers

Tags: php, cache, http-headers, cloudflare

I'm trying to reduce my server load by providing `304 Not Modified` responses for content where appropriate. CloudFlare is my middle man, so they should be sending `If-Modified-Since` headers whenever a cached page has expired, right?

I'm receiving these responses, client-side:

- `CF-Cache-Status: MISS` on first page load
- `CF-Cache-Status: Hit` on page reloads for 20 seconds
- `CF-Cache-Status: EXPIRED` on page reload after 20 seconds

The expired request is forwarded to my server, but doesn't include an `If-Modified-Since` header. How can I get this to work?

```
<?php
$now = time();
header( "ETag: W/\"$now\"" );
header( 'Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $now + 20) );

header( 'Last-Modified: '.time() );
header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=20' );

print('<pre>');
print_r($_SERVER);
print('</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you've configured Cloudflare with `Cache Level: Cache Everything` and `Origin Cache Control: On`, whether in the global settings or as a page rule.

Additionally, you must not set a cookie in the Origin response, `max-age=0`, or a past expires date. Doing so will prevent Cloudflare from caching the page.

Note that some hosts (usually free or shared hosts) will remove any `If-Modified-Since` and `ETag` headers. This is supposedly done because these headers can cause extra requests on the server. If you run the following script twice in a row (6 seconds apart), you should see the `If-Modified-Since` header printed on the page. Otherwise, your `Last-Modified` header was removed before the page was sent to Cloudflare. This is done outside of the PHP script, whether in the Apache configuration or other server settings. Note: as of January 2020, 000webhost removes the `Last-Modified` header and Freehostia does not.

```
/*if( isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE' ] ) )
{
    header( "HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified" );
    exit();
}*/

header( "Cache-Control: max-age=5");
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
echo "<h1>Request Headers received by the server (from Cloudflare):</h1>\r\n<pre>";
print_r( getallheaders() );
echo "</pre>"
```

Answer (score 6):

From my understanding and experience it seems to me perhaps you've misunderstood how CDN caching works:

- From the example you've given, the CDN would not ask your web-server when the file was last modified because you've already told it that the file has expired and will therefore need to be re-fetched anyway.
- Web browsers will only send an `If-Modified-Since` header if the page/resource has been previously cached by the web-browser and came with a `Last-Modified` header when first requested.
- If you send an `E-Tag` header as in your example then the handling of this is not consistent across browsers and you may end up with an `If-None-Match` header in the subsequent request from the browser instead of an `If-Modified-Since`.

CDN's however do not typically behave the same as web-browsers, in some ways more similar to proxy servers or web accelerators:

- If a CDN-cached page has expired, when next requested by a web-browser, the CDN will simply fetch a fresh copy from the web-server, update the CDN-cached copy and forward the resource back to the web-browser in the HTTP response. There would normally be no requirement for `If-Modified-Since` headers reaching your web-server at all, though my testing has revealed that CloudFlare do still issue this header.
- To reduce your server load, enable the CDN to provide a level of caching beyond that already done by the web browsers, by using the `s-maxage` directive. Similar to the `max-age` directive on your `Cache-Control` header, however this one will be observed  by CDN's (and similar services) in precedence over any other headers, while the `max-age` will be observed by the web-browser clients.

  `header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=20, s-maxage=60' );`

  If you use this header, the first request from a web-browser will be a CDN *MISS* but be cached then at both the web-browser and CDN. After the first 20 seconds, the web-browser cached copy will expire. If the page is then reloaded, the CDN will *HIT* for a further 40 seconds returning a copy from CDN-cache to the web-browser in the HTTP response. Sixty seconds after the first request the CDN-cache has expired and a subsequent request will be a CDN *EXPIRED* but otherwise be treated the same as a CDN *MISS* taking a fresh copy from your web-server, and so the loop sequence would continue.

  A more production-ready header, for web-browser caching of 1 hour, and CDN caching of  6 hours might look like:

  `header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=21600' );`

  If you ever needed to publish an update faster than the 6 hour CDN expiry you can always tell the CDN to take a fresh cache from their web-based control panel. With this header each resource would only be fetched from your web-server 4 times a day while the CDN handles all the bulk of the web traffic.

---

*Edited on 11-Nov-2014 @ 12:45pm UTC-0:*

On a side note that might also have an impact, there are issues with your PHP code that may be impacting on its correct operation - your *ETag* and *Expires* header lines of code when I test them produce the following headers:

```
ETag: W/""
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:20 GMT
```

Perhaps instead try these lines in your test so that you can see your sent headers too:

```
<?php
$iClientCacheSecs = 20;
$iProxyCacheSecs = 60;
$dtNow = time();
$dtExpires = strtotime( sprintf( '+%s seconds', $iClientCacheSecs ));
$aHeaders = array();
$aHeaders[] = 'ETag: ' . $dtNow;
$aHeaders[] = 'Expires: ' . date( 'r', $dtExpires );
$aHeaders[] = 'Last-Modified: ' . date( 'r', $dtNow );
$aHeaders[] = sprintf( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=%s, s-maxage=%s',
  $iClientCacheSecs, $iProxyCacheSecs );
foreach( $aHeaders as $sHeader ) header( $sHeader );
echo( 'Now: ' . date( 'r', $dtNow ) . '<br />' );
foreach( $aHeaders as $sHeader ) echo( $sHeader . '<br />' );
echo( '<hr />' );
foreach( $_SERVER as $sParam => $sValue ) {
  if(( strpos( $sParam, 'HTTP_CF' )) !== false ) 
    echo( $sParam . ': ' . $sValue . '<br />' );
  if(( strpos( $sParam, 'HTTP_IF' )) !== false ) 
    echo( $sParam . ': ' . $sValue . '<br />' );
}
```

Comment: So basically Cloudflare doesn't support 304s?

Comment: @skibulk For pages (i.e. not static files) a CDN wouldn't typically support 304's, no. For static files (images, scripts, etc.) CloudFlare does support 304's.

Comment: Great explanation on CDN and caching headers.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that a 304 Not Modified header still requires a request going through to your server.

You properly won't want to send 304 Not Modified headers, you most like want to send a cache expire header, so that the browser doesn't even try to request the resources again. That of course only relevant for static resources (images, scripts etc.).

In my experience CloudFlare only send Last-Modified headers for static resources.

You might want to have a look at CloudFlare's page urls, and give your pages (i.e. not images, scripts, etc.) a Custom caching value other than default?

Comment: There is still a request, yes. But when my CMS takes up to 3 seconds to load (due to shared hosting), I'd rather send a 304. Per my example, I am already sending expires headers.

Comment: See updated answer for the suggestion about page rules.

Comment: I understand that I can change the cache duration. What I'm trying to avoid is needlessly re-rendering my pages when the cache expires.

Comment: Ahh OK, then I have run out of ideas. Good luck!